# Node & NPM linux binary installation

Tags: linux, node.js, npm

I have downloaded and extracted (say /home/varun/node) Node.js linux 64-bit binary bundle from the node.js site. What are the locations I need to add to Path variable for node and npm to work properly?

I have added /home/varun/node/bin to my path and node seems to be working fine. However, npm is throwing errors.

```
node --version
v0.10.21

npm --version
/honme/varun/node/bin/npm: line 1: ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js: No such file or directory
```

Is there anything I have to add for npm to work? When I checked the node/bin/npm install, it has a relative reference to npm-cli.js which is causing the problem. Is this the correct executable for npm or should I be using the one within node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm?

Comment: It'll probably be much easier in the long run to install from your distribution's package manager (if it has node.js) or build from source (make install will put everything in the right place).

Comment: I dont have the necessary permissions to install from Package manager or build from source.

Comment: Works for me. I just untarred the binary package, cd'd into the directory and ran bin/npm. Maybe you moved the executable somewhere? Everything needs to stay in the same place it was originally (relative to the root directory of the tgz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added "/home/varun/node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm" to my PATH variable. (Before node location). Also, have made the following changes for it to work.

```
12c12 
<   node "$basedir/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "$@"
---
>   node "$basedir/npm-cli.js" "$
```